# Python BeautifulSoup can not find all content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using python `beautifulsoup`, `requests` I try to find the string "number" using `find_all()` and using `find()` while iterating the `ResultSet`, I try to scrape "34", "15"

But result is "34", "34".

How should I do.

###### Source

```
<div>
<div style="text-align: center"><br /></div>
<div style="text-align: center"><br /></div>
<div style="text-align: center"><br /></div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<div>test1</div>
<div>How much does the printer weigh?</div>
<div style="line-height: 1.5">
  <b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">&nbsp;34</span>&nbsp;kg</b>
</div>
<div>
  <b style="font-size: 18pt"><br /></b>
</div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">test2</div>
<div style="text-align: center">How much does the chair weigh?</div>
<div style="line-height: 1.5; text-align: center">
<b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">&nbsp;15</span>&nbsp; kg</b>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<b style="font-size: 18pt"><br /></b>
</div>
</div>
```

###### code

```
source = soup.find_all(text="number")
for i in source:
    print(soup.find(text=f"{i}").previous_element)
```

###### result

```
<b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">34</span>kg</b>
<b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">34</span>kg</b>
```

###### I want to scrape like below.

```
<b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">34</span>kg</b>
<b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">15</span>kg</b>
```

Comment: What does `link` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to operate directly on your selected element, get its `.next_element` and grab its `.text`:

```
for i in link:
    print(i.next_element.text.strip())
```

Or with more specific selection via `css selectors`:

```
for e in soup.select('b:-soup-contains("number") span'):
    print(e.text.strip())
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div>
<div style="text-align: center"><br /></div>
<div style="text-align: center"><br /></div>
<div style="text-align: center"><br /></div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<div>test1</div>
<div>How much does the printer weigh?</div>
<div style="line-height: 1.5">
  <b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">&nbsp;34</span>&nbsp;kg</b>
</div>
<div>
  <b style="font-size: 18pt"><br /></b>
</div>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">test2</div>
<div style="text-align: center">How much does the chair weigh?</div>
<div style="line-height: 1.5; text-align: center">
<b style="font-size: 18pt">number<span style="color: #ee2323">&nbsp;15</span>&nbsp; kg</b>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<b style="font-size: 18pt"><br /></b>
</div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
link = soup.find_all(text="number")
for i in link:
    print(i.next_element.text.strip())
```

##### Output

```
34
15
```